# Selecting eclipse.desktop icon doesn't do anything (visible to me), "Exec format error" from shell

Tags: xubuntu, eclipse, .desktop, executable

Trying to execute via desktop icon:

```bash
/usr/bin/eclipse $ ls -l eclipse
-rwxrwxrwx 1 geri geri 61176 Sep 16 19:12 eclipse
```

Right-click on desktop → *Create launcher...* creates:

```bash
~/Desktop# ls -l eclipse.desktop 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 geri geri 195 Dez 12 13:37 eclipse.desktop

~/Desktop# cat eclipse.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=eclipse
Comment=
Exec=/usr/bin/eclipse/eclipse
Icon=/home/geri/Pictures/logo-eclipse.png
Path=/usr/bin/eclipse
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
```

Double-clicking on desktop icon:

[image: Eclipse desktop error]

Selecting <kbd>Launch anyway</kbd> does nothing (visible to me).

Selecting <kbd>Mark Executable</kbd> gives:

```bash
~/Desktop# ls -l eclipse.desktop 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 geri geri 195 Dez 12 13:37 eclipse.desktop
```

Double-clicking on desktop icon now does nothing (visible to me).

I added my user (`geri`) to the `root` group and tried `~/Desktop/eclipse.desktop` and `/usr/bin/eclipse/eclipse` with owner/group `root/root` as well, to no avail.

Checked:

```bash
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.4 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-i386
```

Adding the following to `eclipse.ini` (as per [Is it necessary fix eclipse.desktop to use Eclipse launcher in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/768165/562424)) didn't help:

```bash
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

Adding the following to `eclipse.ini` (as per [How do I create a .desktop file to launch eclipse?](https://askubuntu.com/a/456703/562424)) didn't help (I'm not that far, however, that something [an error] is displayed.):

```bash
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-i386/java/bin
```

Trying from shell:

```bash
/usr/bin/eclipse $ ./eclipse
bash: ./eclipse: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

/usr/bin/eclipse $ readelf -l eclipse
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x400fe0
There are 9 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  ...
```

Why the error if it can be read as ELF file?

`/var/log $ grep "eclipse" *.log` doesn't show anything.

---

N.B.: This really s***s. Installing Eclipse on Windows from scratch is a matter of half an hour, at most, including download and installation of JDK. I'm fiddling around with this and walking through manuals/forums for two half days now.

---

#### UPDATE

```bash
$ uname -vmpi
#40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:25 UTC 2019 i686 i686 i686

/usr/bin/eclipse $ file ./eclipse
./eclipse: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), \
dynamically linked, interpreter /lib, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32,  \
BuildID[sha1]=b621fbc20e80d7ac375ece11a5775fc6686b71c7, with debug_info, not stripped
```

Comment: Is your OS 32-bit or 64-bit? Please add the outputs of `file ./eclipse` and `uname -m`

Comment: Right - so essentially you have downloaded/installed the wrong version of Eclipse for your platform (64-bit versus 32-bit)